# Issue with Alpha/Transparency: Render Looks Different from Viewport

Tags: rendering, transparency

[image]I'm working on rendering an "oil sheen" material that uses transparency, with a mix of "Transparent" shaders, material set to Alpha Blend mode, in Eevee. The material looks exactly how I want in the viewport, but the render result doesn't match it.
I know this is an issue with transparency, because if I render this with a black background, it looks fine. Is there a way to render this with transparency while keeping the look identical to the viewport?
Thank you!

Comment: You will need to save as EXR.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried saving the animation as RGBA OpenEXR with Full color depth, but the result still looks incorrect (I tried opening the EXRs in both Photoshop and Blender's video editor). Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: Depends on where you open the EXR. Remember that the picture is not yet formed in the EXR, and exists only as uniform tristimulus data. That means that you would need to still apply the picture formation in whatever software you attempt to open it in, and the picture formation must match.

Comment: Got it. Would you happen to know how to open this EXR in Photoshop or Blender to preserve the sort of look that I am getting in Blender's viewport?

Comment: I believe you’d need the OpenColorIO plug-in from Fnord. Otherwise use the Filmic Log, and apply the 1D contrast file LUT of your choice using the LUT tool.